# How to run a c# console application from windows task scheduler on server

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

When publishing my console app from VS2017, it creates a .application file that must be run to launch the program. Once I've placed it on the server, I can start it by CMD command, but the program often asks to be installed whenever I start it and if it does this then the task scheduler won't run it.

I just want to be able to run this project daily from the server without having to mess with it. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean you don't want the application to be installed on the server?

Comment: Why not compiled a console app (no installer?) and create a scheduled task on the server to run it regularly?

Comment: Sorry, I do want it to be installed on the server. As it stands now, every time I remote desktop onto the server, it asks me to install the app again when I attempt to run it.

Comment: Daniel, I have published a compiled app to the server, but there is no .exe file to run for a .application file and the task scheduler won't respond if i attempt to point it to the application file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by taking all the dependent `dll`'s and the following files:

- exe
- exe.config
- application
- exe.manifest

These are located in the project folder normally `bin\debug`. if you add all these in a folder and drop this on the server you should be able to run the `exe` without having to install.

from here you should just be able to create a task to run regularly.

Comment: When I publish from VS I get a setup.exe, app.application file, and application files folder with dependent DLLs , application, exe.config.deploy, exe.deploy, exe.manifest. These sound similar to what you are mentioning but I'm not sure if they are what you are talking about.

Comment: @DevDevDev The files you would want to grab are in your project folder normally - `C:\Users\yourUsername\Documents\visual Studio 2017\projects\project name\ project name\bin\debug`. You basicly want all the files out of here innore the app.publish folder

Comment: I understand. You are saying don't use the VS publish at all and just grab the files from the actual project folder myself. I am doing this now and it seems to be working. Thank you!

Comment: @DevDevDev, Yeah that is right, the published files will want you to install but this way you can just run your application without the hassle.